# Java enter key the same as submit button?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

What the program is supposed to do is to mimic the "spin" button with the enter key. The program works and it doesn't crashes but eclipse console is giving me a "***Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTextField cannot be cast to javax.swing.JButton***" error.

```java
//.. gui code
        spin = new JButton("Spin");
        bet = new JTextField("");

        play p = new play();
        spin.addActionListener(p);
        keys k = new keys();
        bet.addKeyListener(k);  
}

private class play implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton src = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if(src.equals(spin)) {
            //do something
        }
}

private class keys implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char c= e.getKeyChar();
        if(c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            spin.doClick();
        }
    }
//.. the other override methods
}
```

**EDIT**

- there are 2 more buttons, I just didn't include them since they worked fine and functioned differently.
- JTextField has a KeyListener because I was filtering out numbers from letters so I would consume the event. Can't have a user bet with letters right?

Comment: JTextFields can have ActionListeners too. These action listeners are invoked... when you press enter in the text field. So you can just add the same ActionListener on the text field and on the button, And you don't need to check what the source is. And even if you have, you don't need to cast is to JButton.

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` in this scenario, it's inappropriate for what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Also, use the `actionCommand` property instead of casting the source, it's generally safer all round

Comment: @MadProgrammer you truly are a mad programmer. I got rid of the `JButton` casting and replaced the conditions with action command and there are no errors. But I still have `KeyListener`, is that okay?

Comment: @asdf *"But I still have KeyListener, is that okay?"* - No, not really.  Apart from the fact that `JTextField` supports `ActionListener`, you can't guarantee that [Enter] will be the "action" key for every platform.  As a general guide, `KeyListener` should never be applied to a text field - there are other and better solutions avaliable

Comment: @MadProgrammer Assuming that I understand what you're saying right now, the reason I have JTextField binded to KeyListener is to filter out numbers and letters. I didn't include this part of the code because this wasn't part of the problem. The [Enter] key works now because I still have `spin.doClick();` in the `keyPressed` method.

Comment: *"I have JTextField binded to KeyListener is to filter out numbers and letters"* then you're doing it wrong.  You should be using a `DocumentFilter` instead.  Many reasons why, but needless to say, you will have less issues if you do.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your `ActionListener` is receiving events from multiple objects, one of which is a `JTextField`. The exception occurs when you try to cast this object to `JButton`:

```
(JButton) e.getSource();
```

There may be a better solution but from what you've shown us the easiest way to prevent the exception is to check that the object generating is an event is an instance of `JButton` before casting:

```
private class play implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        // Check type before casting
        if (src instanceof JButton) {
            JButton bsrc = (JButton)src;
            if(bsrc.equals(spin)) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(e instanceof JButton)` is the wrong condition. The event would not be an instance of JButton. The event's source would be.

Comment: This "works around" the issue, but doesn't solve the underlying issue

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `KeyListener` for this task, `JTextField` already supports `ActionListener` and you could make use of `JRootPane`'s "default button" support as well, so a number of better solutions are available.

You should also take advantage of the `actionComamnd` support of the `ActionEvent` (and `ActionListener`), which will mean you don't have to cast the source, which is safer and makes the solution more re-usable (as it's decoupled).

For example...

```
Play p = new Play();

spin = new JButton("Spin");
spin.setActionCommand(Play.COMMAND);
bet = new JTextField("");
bet.setActionCommand(Play.COMMAND);

spin.addActionListener(p);
bet.addActionListener(p);

//...

private static class Play implements ActionListener {

    public static String COMMAND = "Spin";

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals(COMMAND)) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could make use of the existing `Action`s API.  This allows you to design a self contained unit of work that can be applied directly to a number of Swing components (which already support the `ActionListener` API), but which are also self configurable, neat...

```
private class SpinAction extends AbstractAction {

    public SpinAction() {
        putValue(NAME, "Spin");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // Spin me baby
    }

}
```

And then simply apply it...

```
SpinAction action = new SpinAction();

spin = new JButton(action);
bet = new JTextField("");
bet.setAction(action);
```

See [How to use actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

Comment: If the OP wants to access various methods from the source of the event they will have to cast the source to the appropriate type.  Unless of course it is a listener for one or more of the same type.

Comment: @wjs - why?  There are better solutions then accessing the `ActionEvent` source directly, like using a model to allow passing of information between objects, which is both safer and more decoupled as well as maintaining the concept of encapsulation.  In this particular context, I might be tempted to pass the `JTextField` to the `SpinAction` , as the source of event is actually irrelevant